Project Analog Hypothetical Planet
For my story Project Analog, I was wondering if a hypothetical planet (Let's call it Suria). It has the same size and conditions as Earth with the same axis, tilt, and rotation, as well as one moon. Could Suria orbit between Earth and Mars safely, the minimum distance, and other factors?
Thanks for your time and consideration.

It's hard to know what "safely" means. There aren't a lot more asteroids there than there are at 1 AU as far as I can tell, but that's because of the presence of Earth and Mars. So you are keeping those two and adding one more planet in-between? The reason I ask is that there are long term stability issues - over millions/billions of years planets clan migrate migrate to closer and further orbits due to their mutual gravitational interactions. The three together might be too crowded to last a billion years.
